Implementing Firebase App Check Debug Token in an Angular error:FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403
Subject: Implementing Firebase App Check Debug Token in an Angular Application
Hello everyone,
I recently encountered a scenario where I needed to integrate Firebase App Check into my Angular application to enhance security. While testing, I noticed that the browser console was generating a debug token with the message "App Check debug token: XXXXXXXXXXXXX". This debug token is crucial for testing Firebase App Check locally before deploying the application.
To use this token, I followed these steps:

I copied the debug token from the console.
Then, I went to the Firebase Console, navigated to the App Check section, and under the "Manage debug tokens" option, I registered the new token.

After registering the token, I integrated it into my application by modifying the ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider initialization in my code. Here’s how I updated my provider configuration:
const provider = new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"); // Replace XXXXXXXXXXXXX with your registered debug token
return initializeAppCheck(undefined, { provider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true });

By replacing the placeholder with the actual debug token, I was able to test App Check more effectively in my development environment.
This process ensured that the App Check feature worked correctly without deploying it directly to production, allowing me to address any issues beforehand. Remember, the debug token is meant for testing purposes only and should be replaced with actual production credentials before deployment.
I hope this helps anyone looking to implement Firebase App Check in their projects!
What I Tried: I implemented Firebase App Check by integrating a debug token into my Angular application to enhance security during development.
What I Expected: I expected that by copying the debug token from the console and registering it in the Firebase Console, then updating my ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider initialization, the app would utilize the App Check feature effectively in the development environment without any issues.
What Actually Resulted: The process worked as anticipated, and I was able to test Firebase App Check locally before production deployment, ensuring that the feature functioned correctly and allowing me to address any potential issues beforehand.
